# How to set MySQL binlog retention in hours?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, percona

I'm in a situation where the MySQL log partition is being filled in less than a day. I can't disable binlogs, since I need them for replication.

I know I can set log retention but that accepts days, and a search only showed me this https://serverfault.com/questions/179165/can-expire-logs-days-be-less-than-1-day-in-mysql question, which suggests doing it yourself via scripting.

Since that question is almost 8 years old, I was wondering whether it is possible now.

If it matters, I'm using Percona MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you can now. Since MySQL 8.0.1, while `expire_log_days` still works, the canonical way to setup expiration is by changing [`binlog_expire_logs_seconds`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds), which, as you may guess, has second resolution. The default value since is 8.0.11 is 2592000 (= 30 days), but can be configured as usual on the configuration file to any other period in seconds.

If you cannot use MySQL 8.0 yet, the way to fix this is to use the [`PURGE BINARY LOGS` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html), with `BEFORE` (`PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;`' and setting the [`max-binlog_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size) to an appropiate value (you cannot delete currently-being-written binlog, although you can always force the rotation with [`FLUSH BINARY LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-binary-logs)). You can setup an event to do that regularly, or externally, on a cron/programmed task.

Alternatively, forks of MySQL, like Percona, used to (and still does) allow to setup a max binlog size in bytes -by combining `max_binlog_size` and [`max_binlog_files`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/flexibility/max_binlog_files.html)-, in addition to the days limit.

Comment: Just wanted to mention there's a useful (recent) discussion of this including things to be aware of when purging logs here, might help you decide which way to go https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/03/28/safely-purging-binary-logs-from-master/

Comment: Your link for `binlog_expire_log_seconds` is dead. I wanted to fix it but for some reasons there is no reference for this setting. Any idea what happened?

Comment: Apparently it was moved after my comment to a separate "binlog" options section. I have updated the link. You can see it mentioned here with the wrong link, too https://mysqlserverteam.com/the-mysql-8-0-3-release-candidate-is-available/

Answer (score 4):

Percona Server supports [`max_binlog_files`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/flexibility/max_binlog_files.html), which used in conjunction with [`max_binlog_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size) can keep the number of files (and their aggregate size) within a target range.

Note that `max_binlog_size` is not a hard limit, and most files will overshoot it slightly unless you have very large transactions, which can cause it to overshoot more, since transactions aren't split across different binlogs.  Each log is rotated after crossing the size threshold.